# getting multiple inputs that might contain duplicates the work on each one alone

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing, duplicates

i am working on a code that takes multiple inputs in a while loop , then appends them to list in which i later use each item individually working with their indices , my problem starts when i get duplicates in the input , i have added the index number to the code to help you understand what I mean . since my program is too big i made an example code , what i intend to do with the indices is just an if statement that returns a result if one specific index is equal to something and another if it doesn't . so if your trying this code out add some duplicated lines to the input and leave an empty line at the end of the input by pressing enter at the end .this is the code :

```
    lines = list()
    #line = input()

    def start() :
        #lines = list()
        line = input()
        while line != "" :
              lines.append(line)
              line = input()
              #print(lines) 
    print(" your lines where :")
    for line in lines : 
        print(line + str(lines.index(line)))  


    start()
    print(lines)
```

Comment: I can't find any problems when input contains duplicate strings, if I input 3 lines of text like this: `test this this test`, `make more strings`, `make more strings` , and then 1 line blank (I press enter at the end): `<pressed enter>`, I get this output: `['test this this test', 'make more strings ', 'make more strings']`. the duplicates (the last 2 lines of input) are printed in the `lines` loop as duplicates. Is it ***not*** supposed to include duplicates? What ***is*** your expected output when we *do* input duplicates?

Comment: I think I may understand a little better...I moved the line `start()` (second to last line of code) up to be before the line `print(" your lines where..."`..etc (the line after the function), and I get different output. If I enter 6 lines: `test`, `test2`, `test2`, `test that`, `test those these`, `test those these`, then my last input `pressed enter`, I get `test0
test21
test21
test that3
test those these4
test those these4` the indices `1` and `4` do match the indices of the lines which were duplicates.

Comment: But that seems to be what is expected, I can't re-create any problems when inputting duplicates.

Comment: my problem is identical input-lines are returning identical indices just like what you got in he output if you input : test as a first line and test as a second , you'll get test0 and test0 as an output , yet what i want the output to be is test0 and test1 respectively . hope i made it more clear guess its my fault you didn't understood before.

Comment: Oh I see, maybe I understand better now - when there are duplicates `lines.index(line)` will always return the first index of the line. maybe you want the behavior of [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), what if you change `for line in lines : 
        print(line + str(lines.index(line)))` to --> `for index, line in enumerate(lines): print(line+str(index))` ? but that will always just print the index for each line. then `test, test` will give `test0, test1`

Comment: here's the code I mentioned in the last comment http://repl.it/H2SR/1

Comment: thanks don't know if this would work but i'll try seems perfect for me ,i'll keep you updated when i finish

Comment: if not, I probably don't understand well enough what you're trying to do, let me know and we can improve it until it *is* perfect :)

Comment: i haven't finished yet but it seems working fine till now the whole code is even shorter , i just wanted to upvote you but as i read the rules there where no upvotes on comments therefore i'll just say thank you very much you wouldn't know how grateful i am , its been about a weak since i've been stuck on this googling and trying code after code , after all i am just a beginner at coding , i'll be sure to post you on the final result .thanks again

Comment: no worries, very welcome, we're all glad to help here. beginning coding can be both frustrating and confusing, or enjoyable and a fun challenge. Either way, learn whichever way is best for you and if you get stuck, have questions, or need help in anyway, feel free to post anywhere on this site. Cheers and best of luck.